# Is it possible to use a batch file to log into Google automatically?

Tags: batch-file

I'm fairly new to programming and batch files, I was just curious as to if this is even possible.

Comment: That would require GUI interaction, which is not possible in batch.

Comment: Anything's possible with enough beer.  But this is a very vague question.  By "log into Google automatically," do you mean acquire an oAuth token?  Parse the DOM via XMLHTTPRequest?  Automate interaction with an HTA file?  Interact with Internet Explorer / Firefox / Chrome / Opera / Safari / Lynx / something else?  I daresay all are possible with varying degrees of success by borrowing from other runtime environments (PowerShell, JScript, etc); but probably not to someone who is "fairly new to programming and batch files".

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN  the command line parameters for iexplore are :

```
iexplore.exe [ [ -embedding ] 
               [ -extoff ] 
               [ -framemerging ] 
               [ -k ] 
               [ -noframemerging ]
               [ -nohangrecovery ]
               [ -private ] ]
             [ URL ]
```

Similar command lines options are available for firefox and chrome.
These should work in a batch file. Something like

```
@echo off
set /p SC= Search criteria:
start "" /b "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "http://www.google.com/search?q=%SC%"
pause
```

For more information look at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: He's not trying to search, he's trying to log in.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to is login as a new google user : Well the answer then is "no it's not possible" - not with a batch file.  
You would need to use something like [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to write a script that could detect page contents and respond to popups etc.